# problem unscheduling reports

Tags: reporting, permissions

I have a user that is unable to see the "unschedule report" button in the edit report screen. However I am, as Sys Admin, able to see the button and use. I have checked their profile setting and they have the "Schedule Reports" option. Should this not enable them to unschedule the reports as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Permission required to unschedule reports is **“Modify All Data”**

**reference :** 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_schedule_delete.htm&language=en_US

and there's a related idea to enabled unschedule option for non administrators without the need to Modify All Data permission

**Idea :** https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpiV